# Woocommerce programmatically update custom value of post variation on post save

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to save my product post with custom value of some variation.

For example, I do this, but it does not work, because I think it works before saving of standard product variations.

```
function save_product_meta_box($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    if (!isset($_POST["meta-box-nonce"]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST["meta-box-nonce"], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;

    if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
        return $post_id;

    if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    $slug = "product";
    if($slug != $post->post_type)
        return $post_id;

    if(isset($_POST["bps_variation_id"]) && isset($_POST["bps_variation_price"]))
    {
        $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($_POST["bps_variation_id"]);
        $variation->set_price($_POST["bps_variation_price"]);
        $variation->save();
    }
}
add_action("save_post", "save_product_meta_box", 10, 3);
```

Comment: have you tried logging and commenting out your "return $post_id" - is your code even setting the variation? You could also log the variation to check if it is being set.

Comment: @Innate, yes I tried, and my code does not setting the variation. How can I log the variation?

Comment: what is happening here: $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($_POST["bps_variation_id"]);  you could try error_log($_POST["bps_variation_id"]); (or even just a message at that point to see if your code is making it that far.

Comment: @Innate, I checked these, WC_Product_Variation return normal variation object and $_POST["bps_variation_id"] return normal value.

Comment: I did print($variation->set_price($_POST["bps_variation_price"])) and it did not return anything.

Comment: seems that i should set variation with update_post_meta.

Comment: oh and i had to use $variation->set_regular_price instead of $variation->set_price

Comment: looks like you answered you own question then! post your working code as the answer so other users can benefit ;-)